# How can I prevent users from creating columns [Parse Server]

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm about to launch my application, but I realized that all users can create new columns in a class. Which is a problem as malicious users can create endless columns and impair the performance of my application.

I found   **allowClientClassCreation** which prevents users from creating new class, but I did not find anything that would prevent users from creating columns. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#class-level-permissions

Comment: it's actually documented in all guides, under security section.